# ABAP CDS View : Select from another CDS view

Tags: abap, cds

I have

1. **ABAP CDS view 1 - ZCD1 :** where I am selecting materials from MARA as per a condition and selecting only material columns . This CDS view have a parameter example - MATNR
2. **ABAP CDS view 2 - ZCD2 :** which have multiple joins with other tables and at the end I would like to put a where condition as below

***where MATNR IN ( Select distinct MATNR from ZCD1 )***

I am aware IN and select will not work in ABAP CDS view .

What are the option I have to achieve the above requirement.

Requesting Help

regards

Comment: `SELECT * FROM zcd1 INNER JOIN zcd2 ON matnr = matnr`

Comment: Thanks Jonas . my ZCD1 have a parameter will that make any diffrence ?

Comment: No, it should not. Maybe an association from zcd1 to zcd2 is slightly mote elegant though.

Comment: this is the error i get Entity ZCD2 requires parameter p_matnr

Comment: Then I guess you should create your own view for this scenario.